# C++ Read until tab detected

Tags: c++

This may be a little bit redundant, but is there a short/compact method of reading in a string until a *tab* is reached in C++? Similar to other questions, but I want to keep reading *even if I hit a space*. For example if the STDIN is

```
Cute Kitty    is    fabulous as always
```

Then I want to read in Cute Kitty; is; fabulous as always, three times.
I've seen people do this with regex in files, but how would you do this on the stdin in C++? I want to put it in a string class and whenever I try something like

```
scanf("%s\t", &mystring);
```

It throws up an error because I'm not using an array of chars.
Thanks, please keep answers easy enough for a noob to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to work for me. It basically gets the line that was entered from the user via `stdin` and then reads each character waiting for a tab character (`\t`), or the end of the line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::getline(std::cin,a);
    int index_holder = 0;
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(a[i] == '\t' || (i == a.size() - 1)) {
            std::cout << a.substr(index_holder, i - index_holder) << std::endl;
            index_holder = i + 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I've been trying for hours and this did exactly precisely inconceivably perfectly what was needed. Simple enough I can see where you're coming from too. Please someone with the rep, give this good man a +

Comment: You're right, it reads in the entire line at once, and then breaks up the input into strings between each tab. The method is different but the result is the same. What's the problem?

Comment: You should also be able to do it with only getline. Use the third delimiter argument. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

Split string into tokens. A sequence of calls to this function split str into tokens, which are sequences of contiguous characters separated by any of the characters that are part of delimiters.